# Searching Places using Mapbox

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

I'm trying to get the coordinates of selected search place to show this place on map, I manged to do this and get the coordinates, but when I select it, It doesn't show me the location on map as I wanted
here's what I did..

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let place = self.searchedPlaces.object(at: indexPath.row) as! structName
        let coord = CLLocationCoordinate2D.init(latitude: place.geometry.coordinates[1], longitude: place.geometry.coordinates[0])
    
        let placeAnnototaion = MGLPointAnnotation()
        placeAnnototaion.coordinate = coord
        self.MapView?.addAnnotation(placeAnnototaion)
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. What debugging steps have you tried so far? Have you tried checking your `coord` object, and if it's not 0,0?

Comment: Thanks. when I check for the coord object it actually prints long and lat of selected location. but doesn't  appear on the map
@Glenn

Comment: Any chance your viewport does not contain the annotation? If the annotation coordinate is out of the viewport, it wouldn’t necessarily adjust the map viewport automatically when you call `addAnnotation`.

Comment: I actually tried this and it didn't work either
 created initail annotation for use's current location then called removeAnnotations func
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    ....
      MapView?.removeAnnotations((MapView?.annotations)!)
}
@RafaelAlmeida

Comment: I don’t get it, what exactly did you try?

Comment: i have two views one for the map one for the search bar 
1-on the map view I create Annotation for user's current location 
2- for the search bar for the cell selected (location selected) I added MapView.removeAnnotations(MapView.annotations) so that I can place my new annotaion for the selected location 
@RafaelAlmeida